# Android - MaterialCardView not displaying on API level 27 devices

Tags: android, androidx

I'm creating an XML layout which users MaterialCardViews so I can set the card background colour and corner radius.

It displays as expected in the XML Design tab within Android Studio and also when deployed to a API 28+ device.

When deploying to a API 27 device the card view does not render.

Am I missing something or will MaterialCardViews not work using API 27 and older?

**My Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/emojiBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="1000dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:cardBackgroundColor="#005ECB">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emoji"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Design View**

[image]

**On Device View**

[image]

**My Dependencies**

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cardBackgroundColor` is custom propery of `MaterialCardView`, so it have own prefix set by `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` line on top of XML file (you can exchange beginning with e.g. `xmlns:whatever="..."` and then you may use `whatever:cardBackgroundColor` prefix)

`text` is attribute set for `TextView` present on every Android version so just use default `android:` prefix

so try to put proper prefixes instead of `tools:`

```
tools:cardBackgroundColor="#005ECB"
```

to

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="#005ECB"
```

and

```
tools:text=""
```

to

```
android:text=""
```

`tools` prefix is just configuring/disabling some lint checks, isn't related to attributes of particular `View`s

btw. "design view" have options (drop down lists) for setting orientation, API lvl (OS version), device language and some other params for preview puproses. try to set same API lvl as you have on device - your preview should look exacly same as on device

Comment: Also as a suggestion don't use such a big `cornerRadius` value and trying giving a value in `dp` to `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` because `wrap_content` might be limiting it's size to the popcorn emoji only

Comment: Thanks for the good Feedback! It was the corner radius being too big that was causing the issue. Thanks Again